# What assumptions do I need for a simple gravity pendulum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

What assumptions do I need for a simple gravity pendulum?

I know the bob needs to be regarded as a particle.  The rod needs to be massless and of constant length.  And we ignore air resistance and friction.

But what other assumptions do I need in order to allow the derivation of an equation of motion from, say, Newtonian mechanics?

EDIT

After searching some more online, the only seemingly useful information I could find is this
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)#Simple_gravity_pendulum

Is it accurate?

Comment: The rod must not bend...   You want no forces other than gravity, but I think you've covered that.

Comment: Rigid systems with non-trivial mass distribution are just as easy as a simple pendulum if treated in terms of moment of inertia and torque, so you don't even need a point-like bob or a massless support.

Comment: @dmckee  I see, yes.  But the energy conservation properties of a simple pendulum, when those two assumptions are made, is much simpler to apply.  And results obtained with them don't deviate too much from experimental data.

Comment: Steven I can formulate the so-called "physical pendulum" in exactly the same way. Not that it's obviously better, but it *is* more general, and you seemed to be interested in the minimal assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assume small swing amplitude or face nonlinear behaviour :-) .

Comment: Really? Even without friction or air resistance?  Why?

Comment: The equation of motion is $ml\ddot{\theta}=mg \sin \theta$. This reduces to a harmonic oscillator only for small $\theta$.

Comment: I see.  I can't use small angles, so I'll face the non-linear behaviour.  What are the assumptions of that?

Comment: After searching some more online, the only seemingly useful information I could find is this
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)#Simple_gravity_pendulum

Is it accurate?

Comment: I think you can safely rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, most of the times we assume that gravity is purely acting downwards, while due to the earth not being flat it will vary a bit if the pendulum moves. It goes without saying that this effect is negligible and seldom considered.
For a perfect pendulum you also demand that the rod does not stretch during the oscillations.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: I'm not sure : (  I understand now that gravity needs to be assumed to be constant everywhere, and the ground flat.   But how do I know that's all we need to assume in order to allow the derivation of an equation of motion from Newtonian mechanics?

Comment: After searching some more online, the only seemingly useful information I could find is this
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)#Simple_gravity_pendulum

Is it accurate?